# if the output were executed (conditional sentences)

Tags: conditional-constructions

In the sentence below, I'd like to see if "***were executed***" is correct in the context and if it sounds acceptable to the native ear.

> What would the output be, e.g. on the computer screen, if the code
>   fragment below were executed?

```
 a=5 
 b=2 
 c=a+b 
 print c
```

The reason I'm asking is that it didn't sound as good as

> What would the output be, e.g. on the computer screen, if the code
>   fragment below ***were to be executed***?

Comment: Side note- not sure you’re using “e.g.” correctly, which means “for example”. Could the output appear somewhere else besides the computer screen? I think you vould omit the “e.g.” and it would sound better. Maybe you’re confusing it with “i.e.”, which basically means “in other words”.

Comment: The output could possibly appear on paper by a printer.

Comment: Ok sure, then never mind, "e.g." is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these options is acceptable; "were to be executed" sounds a little old fashioned and formal in the kind of brief question you are asking. I suggest using "were executed"